Luneburg lens in a medium
A Luneburg lens is a spherical lens with a gradient refractive index. It has the interesting property that light coming from focal length of infinity will be focused on the surface of the lens.

The gradient refractive index n(r) of a Luneburg lens of radius R is calculated by the following formula:
n(r)=(2-(r/R)^2)^1/2
The refractive index at the outer layer of the Luneburg lens (r=R) is 1.
To make an Luneburg lens that operates in air would thus require layers of the Luneburg lens to have refractive indexes of 1 and above.
Transparent solids have refractive indices that start at about 1.3, so it would be impossible to make a Luneburg lens that operates in air.
I am wondering if there is a more generalised Luneburg lens formula that accounts for Luneburg lenses in a medium other than air? For example, a Luneburg lens in water.

if the refractivity of the "outside " is $n_0$ then the lens should have index $n_L(r)=n_0\sqrt {(2-|\tfrac{r}{R}|^2)}$

Nanoscale metamaterials can achieve small or even negative refractive indices.

@ANejati  but generally only for a specific wavelength

Interesting methods of manufacture:   https://www.laserfocusworld.com/optics/article/14188413/3d-printed-gradient-index-luneburg-lens-is-fabricated-at-optical-wavelengths   .    And, as @hyportnex wrote, if your lens is embedded in a block of material, all that matters is that the Luneberg lens'  index at the center by sqrt(2) times the interface (external material) index

@CarlWitthoft With any material (including glass or plastic), this type of lens only works at one wavelength, due to dispersion ('chromatic aberration').

@ANejati you wrote "Nanoscale metamaterials can achieve small or even negative refractive indices", indeed but could you please explain what you comment has to do regarding the question of Luneburg lenses?

@hyportnex The question stated it's impossible to make a luneberg lens for air. This is not true, it's possible with nanoscale metamaterials.

@ANejati Of course it is possible, for example, there is no problem with making a Luneburg lens in air, in fact, monster size naval radars use it between 2-18GHz, no problem with chromatic dispersion over three (3) octaves of instantaneous bandwidth!
